# C++ for windows struct

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, struct

I am newbie to developing in C++ for Windows..

I am trying to produce a struc which will have pointer to other struct...

How is this possible?

```
struct InitialNode {  
     Node * nextNode; 
     Node * lowerNode;
} InitialNode;

struct Node {  
     Node * nextNode; 
     Node * lowerNode;
     int value;
} Node;
```

An error is being highlighted at the InitialNode struct where the Node * nextNode; and Node * lowerNode are..

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot beforehand :)

Comment: This isn't specific to Windows, all C++ compilers have the same rules here. They all compile top to bottom, except for class methods (which are always compiled after the class itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several errors:

First, I'm pretty sure you wanted a `typedef`. Also, you need to forward-declare `Node` before `InitialNode`:

```
struct Node;
typedef struct InitialNode {  
     Node * nextNode; 
     Node * lowerNode;
} InitialNode;

typedef struct Node {  
     Node * nextNode; 
     Node * lowerNode;
     int value;
} Node;
```

Your syntax

```
struct A
{
} A;
```

attempts to create an object of type `A` named `A`. Note that the `typedef struct` is a C-style declaration and is not needed in C++. You could very well write:

```
struct Node;
struct InitialNode {  
     Node * nextNode; 
     Node * lowerNode;
};
struct Node {  
     Node * nextNode; 
     Node * lowerNode;
     int value;
};
```

Comment: typedef is not necessary in this case although it is recommended http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: @EdChum I can't see where it says it is recommended for C++. In fact there are several answers that state that for C++ it makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

In c++ an identifier can be used only AFTER it's declared. Try this:

```
struct Node {  
     Node * nextNode; 
     Node * lowerNode;
     int value;
};

struct InitialNode {  
     Node * nextNode; 
     Node * lowerNode;
} InitialNode;
```

Defining `Node` before `InitialNode` should solve your problem